# How to Change the file location of MetroLog in UWP C# application to my c# solution Folder

Tags: c#, uwp, metrolog

```
var root = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
logFolder = await root.CreateFolderAsync(LogFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the MetroLog file is fixed in its source code [line 34](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog/blob/dev/MetroLog.Shared.WinRT/FileTarget.cs#L34), if you want to change it, you should go to the source code and change its position. See [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) to put the file in the accessible location in UWP app.

Also see this similar thread: [Change MetroLog folder and file name in Windows 10 UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081672/change-metrolog-folder-and-file-name-in-windows-10-uwp-app)

Comment: Hello @Breeze Liu - MSFT
now i am able to my create folder in download folder but there is one problem that if i run the program again the new logs are not appending to that log file a created in the download Folder.
Can you guide me how to do that.                                                                                                          
StorageFolder logFolder1 = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyNewFolder");
                logFolder = await logFolder1.CreateFolderAsync(LogFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);